# tweepy documentation

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I just began working on a little twitter-app using tweepy.

is there any kind of useful (and complete) documentation for tweepy?

I googled like hell but didn't find anything.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check the official docs here:

http://packages.python.org/tweepy

Comment: yeah, thanks...but this doesn't seem to be complete - i can't find anything about tweepy.stream etc...

Comment: Yep the Tweepy docs aren't that great, but for most cases the lib itself is pretty fine, you'll most likely have to figure out the stuff yourself. I know it sounds a bit stupid, but while figuring out the stuff you could actually write some documentation for it and give it back to the project afterwards. I had to implement xAuth by myself and now it's in the lib, that way I not only helped me, but I also helped others that will use the lib in the future.

Comment: k, thank you, at least I know now, that it isn't worth googling ;-). I'll find a solution.

Comment: Also stream has an example - so you could go there for inspiration

Comment: I too am finding it difficult to understand just the scope of what tweepy can do.

Answer (score 5):

Prior to work on the 2.0 branch of Tweepy, [the documentation was supposed to be updated at](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/tweepy/G22RQOVOgRI/gfrhVyDW7XoJ) http://tweepy.readthedocs.org/ however that did not happen as expected.

Presently, [there is a closed issue](https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/issues/138) on the [Github repository for Tweepy](https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/) clarifying the status of the project's documentation: as work on 2.0 progresses, documentation will be prepared for posting on the [Tweepy Web site](http://tweepy.github.com/) with the launch of the new version.

As the other answers mention, the version 1.4 documentation at http://packages.python.org/tweepy/html/ seems to be the most complete documentation available presently for Tweepy, despite the version at time of posting being 1.9.

If the above is insufficient, you may wish to investigate the Github repo for [the old documentation that was removed at this commit](https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/commit/2162d65483de7a419ccfd65b0d0b14dfeb70ccfa). I cannot comment on the state nor quality of those doc files.

Comment: thanks for these clarifications.

Comment: Updated further based on recent information from the library's maintainer.

Answer (score 1):

http://tweepy.readthedocs.org/en/v2.3.0/
It's the official documentation and is explained in a very simple language.